# PHP session If else

Tags: php, session, if-statement

I want on page 1 to start a PHP session.

Then on page 2 I'll have to have a if else where if the session is active it have to do nothing and else it have to output this code, if the session is not active.

```
<?php    
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    if(preg_match('/android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))

    header('Location: http://www.url.com);
    } 

?>
```

Can someone provide the code I'll have to put in page 1 and page 2? :)

Comment: No. Stack Overflow is for debugging the code you have written. It is not for code generation, which is what you hire a programmer to do.

Comment: That has to be the most intense regexp for user agent I've seen. That said, you could pretty much eliminate it and still get the point across without making the code unnecessarily long/complicated.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you'll need to start the session on both pages. Make sure to do this before you send any output.

```
session_start();
```

Then, on the first page, just keep a session variable indicating that a session has started.

```
$_SESSION['started'] = true;
```

On the second page, read it.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['started']) && $_SESSION['started']) {
    // Do your check and redirect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `session_start();` to start the session.

Then on login store username as `$_SESSION['user']=$user;`

And the if statement is: `<?php if($_SESSION['user']){ include('page.php'); } else include('another_page.php'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

top of all pages:

```
session_start();
```

Page one add something like:

```
$_SESSION['active'] = true;
```

All other pages test for this like:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['active']) && $_SESSION['active']) {
     // DO STUFF HERE
} else {
     // SESSION IS NOT ACTIVE
}
```

Comment: `defined` is [for constants](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php).

Comment: my bad (my) PHP is rusty, have not used in a while :) fixed and valid.